# How to refresh HelixToolkit ModelVisual3D content on pressed button?

Tags: c#, render, helix-3d-toolkit

starting from a basic HelixToolkit example, I am able to render a mesh. In my .xaml file:

```
 <HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D Name ="viewPort" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True">        
 <HelixToolkit:SunLight/>
 <!--The content of this visual is defined in MainViewModel.cs--> 
 <ModelVisual3D Content="{Binding Model}"/>
```

And in my .cs file:

```
Model3DGroup modelGroup = new Model3DGroup();            
// [... add stuff to modelGroup  as children ]
this.Model = modelGroup;
```

Now, I try to modify my rendered objects when a button is clicked. I tried to implement it through a callback function by updating the model.

```
public void testUpdate(){
       Model3DGroup newModelGroup = new Model3DGroup();            
       // [... add stuff to newModelGroup  as children ]
       this.Model = newModelGroup;
    }
```

This doesn't work: the shown objects are not those added to newModelGroup. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the issue using a PropertyChangedEventHandler

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

Every time the Model is modified, the OnPropertyChangedMethod is called so the new modifications are corectly rendered.

```
this.Model = myNewModelGroup;
OnPropertyChanged("Model");
```